# Recommendation for toggling between map views (e.g. streets and satellite)?

Tags: maps

I have an app with a map page. I would like to toggle between streets map and satellite mode, since in certain areas (especially rural ones), the terrain is better understood that way.

I don't like the native textual <kbd>map</kbd> and <kbd>satellite</kbd> toggle buttons, because they don't fit well into my app design.

**Is there a convention for <kbd>map</kbd> and <kbd>satellite</kbd> image toggle icon, [which aren't associated with a specific brand](https://www.google.com/search?q=map%20icon&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ZYb0U53fNYzN4QScqIHQDw&ved=0CB0QsAQ&biw=1280&bih=566)?**

Comment: The short answer is: no. We try to avoid icon suggestions here because icons, on their own, have no meaning and are always open to user interpretation. Here is more information on [Icon Usability](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/), and a discussion here on UX.SE about [Is there a universally recognizable “Download” button?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54310/is-there-a-universally-recognizable-download-button) that seems applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

Googles implementation is nice - the icons are actually a see through window of what will happen when pressed. The satellite image in the Earth box shows the actual satellite image of that square.

[image]

When clicking Earth, the icon turns into a Map icon, showing the map in that square.

http://www.fastcodesign.com/3027177/behind-google-maps-new-design

Further - don't underestimate the power of writing labels on buttons, it's especially useful when there are no standard icons to use.
http://edwardsanchez.me/blog/13589712

Comment: +1 Thanks, but I am looking for a solution that would fit both Google and Apple maps, and have the form of an icon - the image is way too large and takes too much attention from the user.

Comment: Well, if the icon will be really small I think your best shot is to use a satellite as a starting point. To differentiate a drawn map from a real image (satellite photo) on an icon of just some pixels will be hard. Another approach is to see the Satellite icon (map view) as a state that can be turned on or off. That way you don't have to design 2 icons...